# should i show action button in table header while designing for Webapp

Tags: website-design, web-app, tables, lists, view

I am going to design a table view but I have a problem that I wanted to show the action button. I am confused it is okay to show the action button in the Table header. [image]

Comment: What does the action button do? How is it related to buy?

Comment: no, it is not related to buy, it will change the view from list to chart @Nash

Comment: What's the difference between the chart toggle icons and the chart tab at the top?